# Elasticsearch handling german compound words

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been working a while with the issue of German compound words and would like to know if someone has a modern approach to the problem.

## The Problem

Many German words are actually a combination of many words like for example **Baumhaus** which consists of the words **Baum** and **Haus**. Now to achieve a good performing search it must be possible to search by each individual word.

## Possible Solutions

1. By using a dictionary approach like shown [here](https://github.com/uschindler/german-decompounder). This approach
   is probably the most precise solution I tested. However the
   dictionary is far from complete and hence creates a lot of undesired
   results.
2. The second approach I tried which utilizes prebuilt **Compact Patricia Tries** in form of a [plugin](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-analysis-decompound) was making up for the lacking dictionary. However it of course also causes a lot of undesired results.

Both approaches I found and tested worked but were far from perfect. A combination of both using a [multiplexr token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-multiplexer-tokenfilter.html) created an okay result.

## Not A Solution

My first attempt was the usage of the [N-gram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html). However this presented a crucial problem. While a search for **Haus** should return matches on **Baumhaus** a search for **Baumhaus** should not match on just **Haus**.

## The Question

Since both of the mentioned solutions are rather old, impact performance when combined, and aren't really actively maintained anymore I feel like there must be another approach to this problem.

Any input is appreciated ;)

Comment: Wow, what an interesting problem.  Can you preform an n-gram token filter on the INPUT as well as the search text, so that Baumhaus would be n-gram token normalized to "Baum" and "Haus"? Then, presumably a search would weight "Baumhaus" more heavily than a "Baum" and "Haus" as single tokens by distance? While searching based on libstemmer and sphinx search's approach to German processing, I ran across this link for German stemming in Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html.

Comment: That's a nice approach which I did try. Running the n-gram token filter on the search term however caused pretty much all documents to match which is as to be expected but it seemed impossible to find a score limit that would produce justifiable result amounts. I do implement multiple german stemming algorithms after the decompounding right now to help with matching. They however don't seem to help me with the compound words themselves.

Comment: Using the decompounder approach (which incidentally seems to be a hyphenation, not a dictionary approach) would appear to be the most suitable. However, even when using a larger word list (right now, I use a 31 MB file) does not lead to expected results. The given example of `Kaffeetasse` on the documentation does not break down correctly, instead only returns `Kaffeetasse` twice and `kaffee` once, as opposed to `[Kaffeetasse, kaffee, tasse]`. Using camel cased works, but that is not an expected input, so not viable.

Comment: I have no experience with it, but https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/analysis-hyp-decomp-tokenfilter.html looks like it might be what you're looking for?

Comment: I do use hyphenation decompounder filters. The issue with that is, that it quickly becomes unreliable with words that are not part of the word list. Since I'm dealing with dynamic text including a lot of abstract technical words it sadly doesn't really suffice.

Comment: @pat - Were you able to use Compact Patricia Tries plugin. I have tried installing it but was not successful and I am not sure if it is being maintained currently. Can you please confirm. I have tried versions 5.4.3 and 7.11.1

Comment: We are currently using ES version 6.8.4. I updated the plugin manually in order to be able to install it. While it does work as intended I wouldn't recommend using my version as it may have undesired side effects on performance. That is mainly the reason why I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: I use Hyphenation decompounder with the dictionary from https://github.com/uschindler/german-decompounder (OnlyLongestMatch = true)
Results will be much better if https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-8183 whould be fixed. I created https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/pull/2014 but there isn't any feedback.